# Pandas dataframe not returning the index using the loc method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to retrieve the index of a row within a dataframe using the loc method and a comparison of data from another dataframe within a for loop. Maybe I'm going about this wrong, I dunno.  Here's a bit of information to help give the problem some context...

The following function imports some inventory data into a pandas dataframe from an xlsx file; this seemingly works just fine:

```py
def import_inventory():
    import warnings
    try:
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True):
            warnings.simplefilter("always")        
            return pandas.read_excel(config_data["inventory_file"],header=1)
    except Exception as E:
        writelog.error(E)
        sys.exit(E)
```

The following function imports some data from a combination of CSV files, creating a singular dataframe to work from during comparison; this seemingly works just fine:

```py
def get_report_results():
    output_dir = f"{config_data['output_path']}/reports"
    report_ids = []
    ......
    ...execute and download the report csv files
    ......
    reports_content = []
    for path,current_directory,files in os.walk(output_dir):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(path,file)
            clean_csv_data(file_path) # This function simply cleans up the CSV content (removes blank rows, removes unnecessary footer data); updates same file that was sent in upon successful completion
            current_file_content = pandas.read_csv(file_path,index_col=None,header=7)
            reports_content.append(current_file_content)
    reports_content = pandas.concat(reports_content,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
    return reports_content
```

The problems exist here, at the following function that is ***supposed to*** search the reports content for the existence of an ID value then grab that row's index so I can use it in the future to modify some columns, add some columns.

```py
def search_reports(inventory_df,reports_df):
    for index,row in inventory_df.iterrows():
        reports_index = reports_df.loc[reports_df["Inventory ID"] == row["Inv ID"]].index[0]
        print(reports_df.iloc[reports_index]["Lookup ID"])
```

Here's the error I receive upon comparison

```
Length of values (1) does not match length of index (4729)
```

I can't quite figure out why this is happening.  If I pull everything out of functions the work seems to happen the way it should.  Any ideas?

There's a bit more work happening to the dataframe that comes from import_inventory, but didn't want to clutter the question. It's nothing major - one function adds a few columns that splits out a comma-separated value in the inventory into its own columns, another adds a column based on the contents of another column.

Edit:
As requested, the full stack trace is below.  I've also included the other functions that operate on the original inventory_df object between its retreival (import_inventory) and its final comparison (search_reports).

This function again operates on the inventory_df function, only this time it retrieves a single column from each row (if it has data) and breaks the semicolon-separated list of key-value pair tags apart for further inspection.  If it finds one, it creates the necessary column for it and populates that row with the found value.

```py
def sort_tags(inventory_df):
    cluster_key = "Cluster:"
    nodetype_key = "NodeType:"
    project_key = "project:"

    tags = inventory_df["Tags List"]
    for index,tag in inventory_df.items():
        if not pandas.isna(tag):
            tag_keysvalues = tag.split(";")
            if any(cluster_key in string for string in tag_keysvalues):
                pair = [x for x in tag_keysvalues if x.startswith(cluster_key)]
                key_value_split = pair[0].split(":")
                inventory_df.loc[index, "Cluster Name"] = key_value_split[1]

            if any(nodetype_key in string for string in tag_keysvalues):
                pair = [x for x in tag_keysvalues if x.startswith(nodetype_key)]
                key_value_split = pair[0].split(":")
                inventory_df.loc[index, "Node Type"] = key_value_split[1]
            
            if any(project_key in string for string in tag_keysvalues):
                pair = [x for x in tag_keysvalues if x.startswith(project_key)]
                key_value_split = pair[0].split(":")
                inventory_df.loc[index, "Project Name"] = key_value_split[1]
    
    return inventory_df
```

This function compares the new inventory DF with a CSV import-to-DF of the old inventory.  It creates new columns based on old inventory data if it finds a match.  I know this is ugly code, but I'm hoping to replace it when I can find a solution to my current problem.

```py
def compare_inventories(old_inventory_df,inventory_df):
    aws_rowcount = len(inventory_df)
    now = parser.parse(datetime.utcnow().isoformat()).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None)

    for a_index,a_row in inventory_df.iterrows():
        if a_row["Comments"] != "none":
            for o_index,o_row in old_inventory_df.iterrows():
                last_checkin = parser.parse(str(o_row["last_checkin"])).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None)
                if (a_row["Comments"] == o_row["asset_name"]) and ((now - timedelta(days=30)) <= last_checkin):
                    inventory_df.loc[a_index,["Found in OldInv","OldInv Address","OldInv Asset ID","Inv ID"]] = ["true",o_row["address"],o_row["asset_id"],o_row["host_id"]]
return inventory_df
```

Here's the stack trace for the error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\beefcake-quad\Code\INVENTORYAssetSnapshot\main.py", line 52, in main
    reports_index = reports_df.loc[reports_df["Inventory ID"] == row["Inv ID"]].index
  File "c:\Users\beefcake-quad\Code\INVENTORYAssetSnapshot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 70, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "c:\Users\beefcake-quad\Code\INVENTORYAssetSnapshot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 40, in __eq__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
  File "c:\Users\beefcake-quad\Code\INVENTORYAssetSnapshot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 5625, in _cmp_method
    return self._construct_result(res_values, name=res_name)
  File "c:\Users\beefcake-quad\Code\INVENTORYAssetSnapshot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3017, in _construct_result
    out = self._constructor(result, index=self.index)
  File "c:\Users\beefcake-quad\Code\INVENTORYAssetSnapshot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 442, in __init__
    com.require_length_match(data, index)
  File "c:\Users\beefcake-quad\Code\INVENTORYAssetSnapshot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 557, in require_length_match
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (7150)
```

Comment: Updated original post

Comment: `reports_df.loc[report_data["Inventory ID"] == row["Inv ID"]]`: How does `report_data` relate to `reports_df`? It kind of comes out of the blue. It doesn't have to be wrong (depends on the logic behind it), but it smells a bit.

Comment: Typo bringing in from code to post.  Guess I should have just left most of the code as-is instead of swapping names to make types more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

```
reports_index = reports_df.loc[report_data["Inventory ID"] == row["Inv ID"].index[0]
```

missing `]` at end

Comment: Was a typo in bringing it in from code - have corrected.  Thanks for catching!

Wasn't the issue unfortunatley :(